# Pointer in golang

Tags: pointers, go

I am using golang to parse a json string:

```
str:="{...}"
var f interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), f)

fmt.Println(f)
```

While I got `nil` in the console.

When I change the code to :

`json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &f)`

It will print the json string.

What's going on?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find that.

Comment: Don't ignore errors.

Comment: I think research doesn't help always. Sometimes you can't find answer if you don't know correct question. I also think who has `10.6k` reputation, didn't come here for upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things are happening:

1. You didn't read the documentation.
2. You didn't check `json.Unmarshal`'s return value to check for errors.

From the [fine manual](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal):

> ```
> func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error
> ```
>
> Unmarshal parses the JSON-encoded data and stores the result in the value pointed to by v. If v is nil or not a pointer, Unmarshal returns an InvalidUnmarshalError.

`Unmarshal` takes an `interface{}` because it can unmarshal into all sorts of things (slices, maps, structs, ...) as noted in the documentation.